# OctoberCMS - How to set dynamin value for repeater in filterFields?

Tags: laravel, octobercms

In my OctoberCMS application, I want to change a repeater value depend on another field value change. But it's not working in the **filterFields** model method or **formExtendRefreshFields** controller method.
I am trying like bellow,

```
public function filterFields($fields, $context = null)
{
        
   $fields->item_details->value =  [my prepared array value];
            
}
```

all other property like label, comments working fine in **filterFields** as well.

Comment: hi dear can you share your dependency field config so we can reproduce it on local and share you proper answer

Comment: @HardikSatasiya just create a drop-down and repeater then depend on the drop-down value just change the repeater value in filterFields model method however the fields.